# How can I embed an Autodesk Forge Viewer to a Flask App without CORS errors?

Tags: flask, cors, localhost, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed the [Developer's Guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/) (step 1-3) to create an html file to view my BIM model - this worked fine.

But if I put the same code into a flask app I am not able to view the BIM model. I looked at the requests and found a couple of CORS errors while loading the document with `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load`:

[image: requests]

If I hover over `CORS error` I got a small popup telling me: "Cross origin resource sharing error: HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse".

I tried to change the callback url of my forge app to http://localhost:5001 and  http://localhost:5001/* but this had no impact.

How can I embed an Autodesk Forge Viewer to a Flask App without CORS errors?
Why are there CORS errors on localhost but not on file:///.../index.html?

##### update:

Here is my html file - which works (I removed secrets here). I basically just put the same code into a flask app...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Axpo BIM Viewer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css"
          type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #forgeViewer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 800px;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
        }

        #forgeViewer > div {
            height: 800px !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(() => {
            let client_id = '__client_id__'
            let client_secret = '__client_secret__'
            let documentId = 'urn:__documentId__'

            let htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
            let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);

            get_an_account(client_id, client_secret).then(function (response) {
                initialize_viewer(viewer, response.access_token)
                load_document(viewer, documentId)
            });

        });

        async function get_an_account(client_id, client_secret) {
            var request = {
                "url": 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                "headers": {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                "data": {
                    client_id: client_id,
                    client_secret: client_secret,
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                    scope: 'code:all data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete bucket:read'
                }
            };
            return $.ajax(request);
        }

        function initialize_viewer(viewer, token) {
            var options = {
                env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
                api: 'streamingV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'streamingV2_EU'
                getAccessToken: function (onTokenReady) {
                    var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
                    onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
                }
            };

            Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
                var startedCode = viewer.start();
                if (startedCode > 0) {
                    console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
            });
        }

        function load_document(viewer, documentId) {
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, (viewerDocument) => {
                var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
            }, () => {
                console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="forgeViewer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The preflight response lacks a header [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: someheadername`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) for some header name that occurs in your request. Please share your relevant code to enable more detailed analysis.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thanks for helping. I added the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the issue, however, one thing that will be causing problems is that you're not waiting for `initialize_viewer()` to finish before trying to load a document. Looks like when using the `file://` protocol, you don't run into problems with that though.

I turned that function into a `Promise` so that we can `await` it.

Also, it's better to keep the `client secret` on the **server** side, so I added that to the code too. You'll just have to update the variables in `server.py`

This solution worked fine for me. Maybe your **Flask** app has some different settings that cause the issue?

I had `index.html` in the **templates** folder:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Axpo BIM Viewer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #forgeViewer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #f0f8ff;
    }
    
    #forgeViewer>div {
      height: 800px !important;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(async() => {
      let documentId = "urn:{{ documentId }}";

      let htmlDiv = document.getElementById("forgeViewer");
      let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);

      await initialize_viewer(viewer);
      load_document(viewer, documentId);
    });

    async function get_access_token(onTokenReady) {
      var request = {
        url: "/access_token",
        method: "GET",
      };
      let res = await $.ajax(request);
      console.log(res);
      onTokenReady(res.access_token, res.expires_in);
    }

    async function initialize_viewer(viewer) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        var options = {
          env: "AutodeskProduction2",
          api: "streamingV2", // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'streamingV2_EU'
          getAccessToken: get_access_token,
        };

        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
          var startedCode = viewer.start();
          if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error("Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.");
            return;
          }
          console.log("Initialization complete, loading a model next...");
          resolve();
        });
      })
    }

    function load_document(viewer, documentId) {
      console.log("Loading document");
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
        documentId,
        (viewerDocument) => {
          var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
          viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
        },
        () => {
          console.error("Failed fetching Forge manifest");
        }
      );
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

`server.py`

```js
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

# Update variable values
document_id=""
client_id=""
client_secret=""

@app.route("/")
def run():
  return render_template('index.html', documentId=document_id)

@app.route("/access_token")
def get_access_token():
  headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
  body = (
    f"client_id={client_id}"
    f"&client_secret={client_secret}"
    "&grant_type=client_credentials"
    "&scope=viewables:read"
  )
  print(body)
  res = requests.post("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate", data=body, headers=headers)
  data = res.json()
  return data
```

"Why are there CORS errors on localhost but not on file:///.../index.html?"
I guess the browser has different security concerns for the different protocols. The **Viewer** does not support the `file://` protocol (only `http://` / `https://`) and with some models you'll run into issues because of that - e.g. like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Adam! It's working now! I have a code snippet in my flask app to log to Azure App Insights which somehow interacted with all the request - including the once for autodesk forge. I removed the logging to Azure App Insights for now...